NavigationMixin.Navigate: Use of this is not working to navigate in 'Edit' page of a custom object
NavigationMixin.Navigate: Use of this is not working to navigate in 'Edit' page of a custom object
Below is the code:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
 
export default class OnboardingEditNavigation extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api recordId;
 
    handleNavigateToEdit() {

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({

            type: 'standard__recordPage',

            attributes: {

                recordId: this.recordId,

                actionName: 'edit'

            }

        });

    }

}

It forms a different url which does not take anywhere, and the count parameter in url increases continuously until I close that window
it goes in some infinite loop
Can some one please help me on this

What's the weird URL?  please edit your question with the details.
